# Why jQuery does not run on my xampp on Mac?

Tags: html, jquery, macos, xampp

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

   <head>
      <title>The jQuery AJAX Example</title>
      <script type = 'text/javascript' 
         src = 'https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js'></script>
        
      <script type = 'text/javascript' language = 'javascript'>
         $.getJSON('https://api.flickr.com/services/feeds/photos_public.gne?tags=frenchay,uwe&tagmode=any&format=json&jsoncallback=?',
            function(data){
                $.each(data.items, function(i,item){
                  $('<img/>').attr('src', item.media.m).appendTo('#images');
                  if ( i == 10 ) return false;
               });
            });
      </script>
   </head>
    
   <body>
    
      <h3>Flickr (images tagged with uwe or frenchay)</h3>
        
      <div id = 'images'>
      </div>
        
   </body>
    
</html>
```

Hello I am trying to run this code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

   <head>
      <title>The jQuery AJAX Example</title>
      <script type = 'text/javascript' 
         src = 'https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js'></script>
        
      <script type = 'text/javascript' language = 'javascript'>
         $.getJSON('https://api.flickr.com/services/feeds/photos_public.gne?tags=frenchay,uwe&tagmode=any&format=json&jsoncallback=?',
            function(data){
                $.each(data.items, function(i,item){
                  $('<img/>').attr('src', item.media.m).appendTo('#images');
                  if ( i == 10 ) return false;
               });
            });
      </script>
   </head>
    
   <body>
    
      <h3>Flickr (images tagged with uwe or frenchay)</h3>
        
      <div id = 'images'>
      </div>
        
   </body>
    
</html>
```

If I try to run it on my own machine with xampp on my mac it will not show the photos it is like something about jquery is missing on my laptop.

The code runs in jsfiddle.

Comment: make sure your html doesn't have spaces in the ="" references.This code works here, what's the error you get on your computer?

Comment: Solved you were right. Thank you for the help

Answer (score 0):

For future searches I've attached the solved result here, tightening up the spaces between = and "" fixed it for the original poster of the issue:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

   <head>
      <title>The jQuery AJAX Example</title>
      <script type='text/javascript' 
         src='https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js'></script>
        
      <script type='text/javascript' language='javascript'>
         $.getJSON('https://api.flickr.com/services/feeds/photos_public.gne?tags=frenchay,uwe&tagmode=any&format=json&jsoncallback=?',
            function(data){
                $.each(data.items, function(i,item){
                  $('<img/>').attr('src', item.media.m).appendTo('#images');
                  if ( i == 10 ) return false;
               });
            });
      </script>
   </head>
    
   <body>
    
      <h3>Flickr (images tagged with uwe or frenchay)</h3>
        
      <div id='images'>
      </div>
        
   </body>
    
</html>
```